# Why do Panel elements only receive mouse or stylus events if a Background is defined?

Tags: .net, wpf

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.panel.background.aspx

> Panel elements do not receive mouse or stylus events if a Background is not defined. If you need to handle mouse or stylus events but do not want a background for your Panel, use Transparent.

So my question is: *Why?* Does anybody know the reasoning for this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that input is based on [Hit Testing in the Visual Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx). See especially the *Hit Testing Support* section.

A hit test only succeeds on the rendered content (i.e. a rendered Geometry) of a Visual. A Panel eventually renders a filled RectangleGeometry as background when you set its `Background` property.